# How to configure dotnetcore 3 site to return 401 with custom authorization filter rather than redirecting to AccessDenied page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I've got a site using the new dotnetcore3 angular template.  I've created a custom authorization filter that's currently extremely simple

```
public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly string _claim;

    public ClaimRequirementFilter(string claim)
    {
        _claim = claim;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {

        if (_claim != "test")
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ClaimRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public ClaimRequirementAttribute(string claimType) : base(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] {claimType };
    }
}
```

```
    [Route("{jobId}")]
    [ClaimRequirement("testfail")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetJob([FromRoute] Guid jobId)
    {
      //stuff
    {
```

However, whenever a request fails (which will be all of them right now), it 302s me to the AccessDenied page with a returnUrl of the URL I  was trying to hit.

However, since this request is being made from my angular client, I would rather it just return a 401 (or 403 since in this case it's because the loggedin user doesn't have permission to do what they're trying to do), and I'm not sure how to configure it.

Per Ruard's request, here is my Startup configuration

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
              options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );

            services.AddTransient<EmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddScoped<IRazorViewToStringRenderer, RazorViewToStringRenderer>();
            services.Configure<EmailServiceConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailServiceConfiguration"));
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                    {
                        options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/auth/login";
                        options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/auth/logout";
                    })
                    //.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.AddAuthentication()
                    // .AddGoogle(options =>
                    //   {
                    //     IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
                    //     options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                    //     options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
                    //   })
                    .AddIdentityServerJwt();


            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Identity/Account/Login", "/auth/login");
            });


            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // options.AddPolicy("RequireAdmin", policy =>
                // {
                //   policy.RequireRole("Admin");
                // });

                // options.AddPolicy("CreateInternalUsers", policy =>
                // {
                //   // policy.RequireRole("Admin");
                //   policy.RequireClaim("CreatePPGUser");
                // });
            });

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
            services.AddControllers()
              .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
              {
                  options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
              });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            context.Database.Migrate();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                  );

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    // spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });

            CreateUserRoles(services).Wait();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a controller that serves as api. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/web-api/#controllerbase-class):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Methods from this controller will return the StatusCode instead of redirecting the user to a view.

---

**Update**

Based on your startup, it seems that you are not setting the CompatibilityVersion:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/webapi#configure-routing), this is required in combination with ApiController:

> The preceding change:
>
> - Is required to use the [ApiController] attribute at the controller level.
> - Opts in to potentially breaking behaviors introduced in ASP.NET Core 2.2.

In your case, assuming version 3.0:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

Comment: My controllers actually already are ApiControllers, weirdly.  Sorry I forgot to put that in the OP question

Comment: added my Startup (minus a bunch of business logic around initializing identity)

Comment: @AlexKibler Did you notice the update of my answer? And were you able to get it working?

Comment: Thanks for the followup! I missed your edit. It actually doesn't seem to be working for me. I added SetCompatibilityVersion like you suggested, and I'm still just getting redirected to an AccessDenied page